# What is the type for Mongoose collection model when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

Hello guys this is my first time using TypeScript so I want to build an Auth controller class which takes in **mongoose model** in constructor and many others but the problem that I am facing I seem to not find the **datatype / type** for a mongoose model

When I hovered on top of the mongoose model I see the following: `const model: Model<Document, {}>`

- So I thought that `Model` is the **type** which I need to specify

**This is how I tired to make this constructor**

```
import { Model } from "mongoose";

class AuthController {
  constructor(userModel: Model) {}
}
```

- But I am getting this error message: `Generic type 'Model<T, QueryHelpers>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.t`
- Can I please get some help on this I was trying to avoid using the **any** datatype because I want to make sure that the constructor takes in those specified parameter types

Comment: I've never used a constructor with mongoose before. 

A Model type can be defined as `Model<User>` where you have to define User. `interface User { name: string; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this using

```
Model<UserDocument>
```

Where `UserDocument` is a type that extends mongooses `Document` type, like:

```
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
UserDocument = Document & { email: string } // Whatever user fields you have
```

Another way to solve this would be to have your User Model exported from its file:

```
export default mongoose.model<UserDocument>('User', UserSchema)
```

Then to use that exported model in your constructor

```
import UserModel from "./user-model";

class AuthController {
  constructor(userModel: UserModel) {}
}
```

Comment: Quick question so even if I were to pass *Document* as the datatype that would still hold as a valid mongoose model?

Comment: That is the datatype of the model. So it's what the model will return when queried, etc.
`Model<UserDocument>` is saying "This is a mongoose model, that operates (find, update, etc) against UserDocuments"

Comment: Okay but when I write ```userModel: Document``` in my constructor the instance I try to use the ```.findOne()``` methods I get an error that the following method is not available

Comment: That is correct - `Document` is not the correct type. `Model<Document>` is. But that won't have any metadata on your actual documents, so `Model<UserDocument>` would be the way to go here.

Comment: Oh Yea I see what you mean thanks now it's working nicely thanks a lot...

Comment: doesn't work for me, I cannot access typical properties of the IObject interface